# Uninitialized Constant within Simple Ruby File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably because of my limited knowledge of ruby, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with this ruby file.

```
   module RW
      FIELD_ONE = 0
      FIELD_TWO = 0xFF00FF00

      def self.CommonHeader(idxStr="")
        indent = "   "
        outStr = ""
        outStr << indent << "  APPEND_PARAMATER"
        return outStr
      end
end
```

to me everything seems initialized in this file... am I wrong?

Comment: Please post the actual error as what you have provided lacks enough context to assist in any manner that would not be complete conjecture. That being said the code itself makes no sense since constants `FIELD_ONE` and `FIELD_TWO` as well as parameter `idxStr` are never utilized. Calling `RW.CommonHeader` will always result in `"     APPEND_PARAMATER"`

Comment: @engineersmnky They are called with a require command from another file. What I am trying to figure out is syntax wise it appears that these are fine

Comment: Also you can replace that entire method body with `"APPEND_PARAMETER".rjust(5)`. you don't even need return as its implicit.

Comment: And as @engineersmnky has pointed out this is only half the picture. We need to see the other file where you are requiring / referencing the constant as well as the actual error message. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example